# How to run Google-sheets query on text cell containing asterisk

Tags: sql, regex, google-sheets, escaping, google-sheets-query

When I use this query in Google sheets

```
=QUERY('Kontoutdrag länsförsäkringar'!$A$3:$F$1000186;"SELECT sum(F) WHERE B >= date'" & TEXT(DATEVALUE(J$4);"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND B <= date '"& TEXT(DATEVALUE(J$5);"yyyy-mm-dd") &"' AND D matches '" & JOIN("|";$T10:$CZ10) &"' AND D != '' label sum(F)'' ")
```

It will skip any cell that contains an asterisk somewhere in the text, the character

```
*
```

The error is in this match part

```
AND D matches '" & JOIN("|";$T10:$CZ10)
```

If the D column's text (and the corresponding, identical cell in the join range) contains an asterisk it will not match.

Is there a way to escape this so that I can have cells with the asterisk in the text?

This value will work

```
K Batteriexp
```

This value will not be picked up by the query

```
K*Batteriexp
```

Comment: * is a quantifier in regex (meaning: zero or more times). Did you try changing 'matches' to 'contains' ?

Comment: Have you tried @JPV's suggestion MattWelander? Does that work for your situation?

Comment: @JPV That won't work. OP is using `|` OR operator for regex

Comment: Yes, of course. Probably didn't have enough coffee this morning. ;-/ Thanks for pointing that out @TheMaster.

Comment: I'm afraid Using contains could create double matches, rule "mat" would match transactions with text "matmagasinet" and "matsmart" right?

Answer (score 0):

If asterisk is the only problem, You can escape it using regex:

```
AND D matches '" & ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("|";REGEXREPLACE($T10:$CZ10,"\*","\\*")))
```

This

```
K*Batteriexp //Means 'K' repeated 0 or more times
```

becomes

```
K\*Batteriexp //means a literal *
```